# How to make the contents of an array get printed like a word as a string

Tags: java

I will be making a hangman game in the console. One of the tasks is to print dashes and replace them with the character guessed by the user. Been doing this and that and everything worked. I used two string arrays. One of them I fill with dashes and one with the contents of the word that has to be guessed. All of the filled indexes are filled with individual characters like:

```
        Arrays.fill(underDashWord, "_");
        for (int i = 0; i < wordChosen.length(); i++) {
            wordByLettersArray[i] = String.valueOf(wordChosen.charAt(i));
        }
```

I used String instead of char in order to use .equals after. Here is the code where I use it, you can also see why I needed it:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < underDashWord.length; i++) {
                if (wordByLettersArray[i].equals(userGuess)){
                    underDashWord[i] = wordByLettersArray[i];
                }
            }
```

Basically by doing that I get to check the exact position of every character that has been guessed. If guessed correctly it prints the character on the position where it is meant to be, like if we were to guess the word "milk" and guess "i" this shall be shown: _ i _ _. I use  `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(underDashWord));` which unfortunately prints [ _, i, _ , _ ].
I hope you understood my problem and Ill be very thankful if you can tell me how to print the array this way!

Comment: [`String.join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-)

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly! I created a string that equals "" and joined it to the dashes, the console prints exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate through the list and append it to a string.

```
String output = "";
for (int i = 0; i < underDashWord.length; i++)
    output += underDashWord[i] + " ";
System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but there is a problem with it. Since im looping the program when I ask for a letter to be guessed and lets say someone does get a letter, the dashes and letter have to be printed. its all right the first time but after we try to guess a second time all the dashes get appended to the string again and this continues untill the end of the loop. Something like this gets printed: _ i _ _ _ i l _ m i l _milk